# Is there way to build own library with internal/hidden package

Tags: java, android, package

As you may know Android SDK has some hidden classes in `internal` package. Could I do the same in my own library? I would like to hide some of classes for end developers?

Comment: Make those classes as private with package name containing something like internal?

Comment: Note that as a developer you can still access the hidden internal Android APIs, for example via reflection.